# Get highlighted state for NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbuttoncell

I have a `NSTableView` that contains a `NSButtonCell` in one of the columns. To draw a custom background in neighbor cells (based on `NSTextFieldCell`) I use `isHighlighted` method:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
     if ([self isHighlighted]) {
     //here I draw the cell background
```

But for `NSButtonCell` *`isHighlighted`* shows only the button pressed state.

How to determine when the `NSButtonCell` is selected, i.e. when it's highlighted in the row?